# Select text from two para in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

So I have to automate selecting text from below 2 paragraphs in Selenium webdriver. I want to select from **p1** "Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be automated as well." until this in **p2** "Selenium has the support of some of the largest browser vendors who have taken (or are taking) steps to make Selenium a native part of their browser." Can someone please help me with this?

```html
<div class="para1" id="p1" first-line="2" turnover="1"><span class="link">Selenium automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be automated as well.</div></div>

<div class="para2"><a name="p2"></a><div class="paraText" id="p2" first-line="2" turnover="1">Selenium has the support of some of the largest browser vendors who have taken (or are taking) steps to make Selenium a native part of their browser. It is also the core technology in countless other browser automation tools, APIs and frameworks.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think Selenium has the capability of selecting *part* of the text, you might have to filter that manually

Comment: So is there a different way that I can write a separate method in java to select the text and call the method in my test? Does that going to work?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm only familiar with Selenium via Python.